# What is the difference between window.app=new Vue({}) instead of const app = new Vue({}) in app.js in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

So what is the difference if I use window.app in main.js in Vue instead of const app?

```
import question from './components/Questions.vue';

Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
window.App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { question }
});
```

instead of

```
import question from './components/Questions.vue';

Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { question }
});
```

So the reason I used window.app because I want to call a method from question component using an external jQuery function to execute the Vue method, like App.component.metho() then it works. But is this safe approach?

Comment: I don't really get why you are mixing vue and jQuery, Vue can do everything jQuery can, and more. The difference is the variable scope. when you use widow.app, it will be available everywhere where window is available

Comment: @Gert B. I use laravel with vue so the blade where the vue component is called below is a jquery function where I call the vue method. Is there a best way to call a vue method  outside vue component?

Comment: Depends on what the method does. It seems strange to me to call vue methods from outside of the vue app ..

Comment: Stick with `const app = ...` when ever you can. That would be better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every browser have `window` object inbuilt which can be access from everywhere in client side java script

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

so if you use

```js
window.App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { question }
});
```

then your assign a variable  `App` to `window` object so you can use `App` to get vue instance in anywhere in your application

and if you use

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { question }
});
```

this then you cannot access `app` variable anywhere in you application

Comment: is it safe to use it?

Comment: @Sensuz yes, it is safe to use.